# Python requests set-cookie not properly set

Tags: python, cookies, python-requests

The `'Set-cookie'` is not properly returned to the requests session.

Code:

```
import requests

r = requests.Session()
respond = r.put("192.168.1.111/getC", json=data, verify=False)
```

Let us check cookie of the response (empty)

```
respond.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

Let us check the header

```
respond.headers
{'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'Date': 'Sun, 30 Jun 2019 11:19:05 GMT+00:00', 'Accept-Ranges': 'bytes', 'Server': 'Restlet-Framework/2.3.12', 'Set-Cookie': 'Credentials=sdf34dsfsdf23rsdfsdf234r23r23r; Path=/; Domain=blah.local; Secure'}
```

Let us check the cookie of the session (empty)

```
r.cookies
<RequestsCookieJar[]>
```

I think `requests` should automatically load the `set-cookie` to the session, right? Why it is not working here, and how should I set the cookie using the header here?

Comment: "I think requests should automatically load the set-cookie to the session" What does the documentation say?

Comment: @DeepSpace I didn't find it in the doc, but I recall it should....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there's no problem with `requests` here, probably it's a server who gives you the wrong response.

It looks like `requests` does not recognize this `Set-Cookie` response header because of inappropriate `Domain` [section](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Scope_of_cookies) in it:

```py
'Set-Cookie': 'Credentials=sdf34dsfsdf23rsdfsdf234r23r; Path=/; Domain=blah.local; Secure'
```

I've set up a test web server on `localhost` and  tried to set `Set-Cookie` header manually, exactly as it is above, and cookies in response were empty.

Then I've removed `; Domain=blah.local; Secure` part from `Set-Cookie` header (`Domain` and `Secure` directives [are optional](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie)) and everything worked fine.

Comment: I just tried that, exactly as what you have said, the `domain` and `sceure` affects that. But why is this special? Is this a bug of `requests`?

Comment: As I've mentioned above – this is not a `requests` bug. Your local server gives you wrong `Set-Cookie` header – `Domain` should either match domain you're making request to, or be removed completely (read links in the answer).

Comment: Some websites beyond our control returns `Domain=blah.local`. And evidently these still work in browser, but not in request.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `Session` before handling requests:

```py
import requests
s = requests.Session()
response = s.put("192.168.1.111/getC", json=data, verify=False)
```

As mentioned in documentation https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/ :

> Session Objects
>
> The Session object allows you to persist certain parameters across requests. It also persists cookies across all requests made from the Session instance, and will use urllib3’s connection pooling. So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase (see HTTP persistent connection).

Then, check cookies not within the `response`, but at session level:

`s.cookies`

Comment: Check cookies at `session` level: `s.cookies`

Comment: I still dont understand, I checked both of the respoinse cookie and session. See my last code block

Comment: Can you send the URL you request ?